# How to create a two function button in Adobe Flash- light on/off?

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

I am trying to create a light switch as an exercise and I am struggling with the on/off functions.
The idea is to create a button (with a if -loop) that turns the light on on mouse click and turns it off when you click one more time.

It must be something very simple. Could you please give me any tips?
Thanks in advance!

```
Mouse.hide(); // Standard Mauszeiger wird nicht angezeigt

kaefer_mc.mouseEnabled = false; //dadruch wird die Fähigkeit der Käfers auf Mausklick zu       reagieren, deaktiviert. und der eigentlich Muaszeiger der unsichtbar ist funktionier.
stop();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, folgeMaus); //stage bedeutet die ganze Bühne, MOUSE_MOVE heißt Mausbewegung

function folgeMaus(ereignis:MouseEvent) {
            kaefer_mc.x = stage.mouseX; //Mauskoordinaten für xAchse
            kaefer_mc.y = stage.mouseY; //Mauskoordinaten für yAchse
}

knopf_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, schalten);

function schalten(ereignis:MouseEvent) {
            if(knopf_bt.enabled = false){
                           lichtAn_pic.gotoAndPlay(1);
            }else{
                           lichtAus_pic.gotoAndPlay(2);
                           }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have several solutions**

If lichtAn_pic is a black rectangle (visible or not)

```
function schalten(ereignis:MouseEvent):void {
            lichtAn_pic.visible = !lichtAn_pic.visible;
}
```

If lichtAn_pic is a black rectangle (it's alpha changes)

```
var light:Boolean = true;
lichtAn_pic.alpha = .3;

function schalten(ereignis:MouseEvent):void {
            lichtAn_pic.alpha = (light) ? 0 : .3;
            light = !light;
}
```

If lichtAn_pic is a MovieClip with light in frame 1 and night in frame 2 (because  it's unnecessary to create 2 movieclips for that)

```
function schalten(ereignis:MouseEvent):void {
            if (light) {
                lichtAn_pic.gotoAndStop(1);
            } else {
                lichtAn_pic.gotoAndStop(2);
            }
            light = !light;
}
```

**Remark**

On `MOUSE_MOVE` you can get a better screen display using `updateAfterEvent()`:

```
function folgeMaus(ereignis:MouseEvent):void {
            kaefer_mc.x = stage.mouseX;
            kaefer_mc.y = stage.mouseY;
            ereignis.updateAfterEvent();
}
```